# UrlFetchApp.fetch() incomplete content on google.com

Tags: html, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm starting with Google Apps Script coding.

So I tried this example: [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=de#fetch%28String%29)

```
// The code below logs the HTML code of the Google home page.
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
 Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

I'm receiving the tags from:

```
<!doctype html> to <style>
```

But there aren't these tags:

```
</head>, <body>, </body> or </html>
```

Is it an incorrect Google Apps Script example or is it a mistake on my part?
How can I response the complete HTML code from google.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logger.log automatically truncates the strings displayed after a certain length. You are receiving the entire page, but only seeing the first part in the Log.

```
 // The code below logs the HTML code of the Google home page.
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
 var content = response.getContentText();
 Logger.log(content);
 //log last 1000 chars of content
 Logger.log(content.substr(-1000));
```

Comment: @cameron Roberts. Could you tell me what regex should i use to get title and url form  content.subster(-1000)?