# Google script UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText() returning incomplete HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I'm using the following script to extract the source HTML from a webpage:

```
var url = "http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/dividends.do?by=asxCodes&asxCodes=BHP";
var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
```

Inspecting the xmlFeed text I see that it has been truncated compared with the page source I see using the browser, and the data I'm looking for (the table of dividend data) is not there. In fact the only remaining HTML seems to be that within the <APM_DO_NOT_TOUCH>
tags.

I thought this may have been because the dividend data was generated by a script, but after disabling javascript in my browser I can still see the data in the page source (condensed version below):

```
<table class="datatable" id="dividends" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th class="row" scope="row">
            <a onclick="trackAsxCodeClick('BHP')" href="/asx/share-price-research/company/BHP">BHP</a>
            </th>
            <td>BHP BILLITON LIMITED</td>
            <td>
                18.521c
            </td>
            <td>
                01/09/2016
            </td>
```

I have also successfully scraped the data using the beautifulsoup library in Python, which tells me the data must be in the source HTML and not generated by a script.

Comment: Try setting `xmlFeed.substr(-1000)` as stated in this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26430917/5995040). This is to check if you are receiving but only seeing part part of the page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not the issue. I have exported the HTML to file and confirm that it is well over 1000 characters (64945).

Answer (score 0):

If data is generated by a script and to extract it, u can try using some other HTML source code generator website and getting that generated result

```
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.joydeepdeb.com/tools/support/print-code.html?v='+your_url_with_script).getContentText();
```

(this or any other source code provider service)
this will give the complete source code processed by js too. and in Logger.log() it's limited to display all results. So, send the result to mail using
GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "Result", html);
and analyse